# Substitute for LM2937 (5v to 3.3v) regulator

Tags: components, pcb-fabrication

I made a fatal mistake of designing a pcb without checking the availability of the component in my locality(lm2937 3.3v)..

Shocked to know that it is not available anywhere in India..

Though I have the pcb ready with me, I am unable to complete my project because of this issue..

So, I am looking for some other 3.3v voltage regulator that has the same pin out(TO-220 Plastic Package)..

I need your help people..

The devices getting powered by this are Pic32, Micro SdCard, Xbee module(if it does matter)..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

[DigiKey](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=LM2937ET-3.3-ND) has 954 available, [Mouser](http://be.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Parallax/601-00513/?qs=bZ3KlHYEm0agkA%2fFRP6FOw%3d%3d) can dispatch 53 immediately.
If you need just a few, talk to a distri, like [EBV](http://www.ebv.com/) and beg :-) for samples. If you need higher quantities, the same distri should be able to help you. Distribution is worldwide, and doesn't stop at India's borders! Neither do Internet orders, neither do phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

Googling says LD1117V33 or LM3940 (both are TO-220 but with higher current rating)

Alternatively just use a LM317 (adjustable) and directly solder the necessary voltage resistors on the back of the board (ugly I know ;-) )

Comment: The LM317 isn't an LDO and is not suitable for 5V to 3.3V.

Comment: Depends on the application, but you won't be able to draw full load current (no more than 500mA) or have it reliably working at very low temperatures. In the LM317 datasheet of National there is a graph 'Dropout voltage' showing the least required voltage drop for a stable sitation. 5-3.3V=1.7V, so under some circumstances it will work I guess, but not preferred.

Comment: @Hans - nice graph, but reference voltage and line regulation are only specified for **(\$V_{IN}\$ - \$V_{OUT}\$ ) > 3V**. If you can't rely on your reference voltage you may as well not use a regulator at all.

Comment: Agreed, it would probably get to the stable point, but the performance will be poor compared to a regulator with a bit more 'headroom'. I wouldn't recommended doing it at all, I guess it's graph that shows the absolute minimum required for a stable output on a constant current device with near constant input voltages.